# Macro for calling n macros in SAS

Tags: sas, macros

I have written a code that will create multiple macro variables containing IDs. However a macro variable can contain only 65534 charakters. Each of my macro variables ACC_i contain 65k variables. I want to create  macro variable that will contain macro variables ACC_1 - ACC_i so when used in code all of the macros will be called.

Here is the code i have so far, appriciate any help

```
%MACRO LOOP();
proc sql; select Count(*) as CNT ,MAX(LENGTH(Column1)) FORMAT 2.0 as LEN into: CNT, :LEN from table
; quit;
%put &CNT. &LEN.;

%let RUNS = %sysfunc(CEIL(&CNT./(65534/&LEN.)));
%LET OBS = %sysfunc(FLOOR(((65534/&LEN.))));

data TEST;
set &table.;
run;

%put &RUNS.;
%put &OBS.;
%let ACC = .;
%global i;
%DO i = 1 %to &RUNS.;
    %global ACC_&i.;
    proc sql inobs=&OBS.; 
        select input(&ID.,16.) FORMAT 16. as ACC_&i. into: ACC_&i. SEPARATED BY " ," 
        from TEST 
    ;quit;

    data TEST;
    set TEST nobs=count;
    if _n_ <= &OBS. then delete;
    run;

    
%END;
%mend;
%LOOP();
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to do with this set of variables? No (macro) function will process more than 65,534 characters at once, so for example `%scan(&ACC_1 &ACC_2, ..)` or `%sysfunc(length(&ACC_1 &ACC_2))` won't work even if each variable itself doesn't exceed the limit. I can think of a way to get around this in some cases but it would require re-implementation of the specific function(s) that you need and it will *definitely* not be fast. A dataset with one row per value is probably the better option if you need access to all at once (which is what my solution would boil down to anyway).

Comment: Don't do this Tim.  Learn how to SORT and then use the BY statement, and the CLASS statement in various Procedures.  If you want to run a bunch of code for each row of a control data set, learn about CALL EXECUTE, or DOSUBL.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, there is likely a more optimal way of achieving this by using tables. But, this is a fun programming challenge so here's a solution that does what you want.

The easiest way is to create a table that cuts your IDs into groups. We'll cumulatively count the length of all the values, add 2 to it to account for a space and a comma, and increment a group counter whenever we exceed 65534.

Note that if your IDs are numeric, convert them into characters first with `strip(put(num_var, 32.))`, otherwise SAS will not give the expected answer.

```
/* Sample data */
data have;
    call streaminit(12345);
    do i = 1 to 100000;
        id = put(rand('integer', 100000), z8.);
        output;
    end;
    drop i;
run;

data id_groups;
    set have;

    /* Add +2 to account for ', ' */
    cumulative_len+(length(id)+2);

    /* Init first value, reset cumulative length, and increment group counter */
    if(_N_ = 1 or cumulative_len > 65534) then do;
        group+1;
        cumulative_len = length(id)+2;
    end;            

    call symputx('ngroups', group);
run;
```

```
id          group   cumulative_len
00058330    1       10
00099363    1       20
00058789    1       30
...         ...     ...
00051947    1       65520
00066223    1       65530
00064104    2       10
00060774    2       20
...
```

We know the total number of groups, so we'll loop through them and create a macro variable for each one. Then we'll save all of those into a single macro variable called `all_macvars`.

```
%macro create_vars;
    %global all_macvars;

    %do i = 1 %to &ngroups;
        %global id_&i.;

        proc sql noprint;
            select id
            into :id_&i. separated by ', '
            from id_groups
            where group=&i
            ;
        quit;

        %let all_macvars = &all_macvars %nrstr(&id_)&i.;
    %end;
%mend;
%create_vars;

%put &all_macvars
%put &id_1
```

```
&id_1 &id_2 &id_3 &id_4 &id_5 &id_6 
&id_7 &id_8 &id_9 &id_10 &id_11 &id_12 
...

00058330, 00099363, 00058789, 00085747, 00082469, 
00028057, 00064740, 00038192, 00044896, 00087579, 
00051839, 00084268, 00027839, 00093355, 00018740,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get around the 65k limit by making a macro variable that references other macro variables.  Let's make a small example using two variables to demonstrate.

```
data _null_;
   call symputx('var1','A B C D');
   call symputx('var2','E F G');
   call symputx('all','&var1 &var2');
run;
```

To test we can use use %PUT.

```
6    %put &=var1 &=var2 &=all;
VAR1=A B C D VAR2=E F G ALL=A B C D E F G
```

The use of CALL SYMPUTX() to make the ALL macro variable makes it much easier to get the &var1 string into the macro variable without any macro quoting.

So for your example you could make a macro variable with &ACC_1 &ACC_2 ... with a simple data step like this.

```
data _null_;
  length str $32767 ;
  do i=1 to 5;
    str=catx(' ',str,'&acc_',i));
  end;
  call symputx('all',str);
run;
```

So just use a data step to make all N+1 macro variables at once.  But since you are using a data step you will be limited to 32767 bytes per individual macro variable.  So for your example HAVE dataset here is a data step that will make macro variables named VAR1 to VARn and the extra macro variable named ALL.

```
data _null_;
  length one all $32767 ;
  retain n 1 one all;
  set have end=eof;
  len=length(one);
  if len > (vlength(one) - length(id) -1 ) then link write;
  one = catx(' ',one,id);
  if eof then do;
    link write;
    call symputx('all',all); 
  end;
return;
write:
    put n= _n_= len= ;
    call symputx(cats('var',n),one);
    all = catx(' ',all,cats('&var',n));
    n+1;
    one=' ';
return;
run;
```

To test it with smaller lists just modify the length you define the ONE variable.  For example if I use Stu's example data step to make 100 ID values and set the length of ONE to $200 I get:

```
397  %put &=var1;
VAR1=00072660 00092691 00069441 00076914 00000296 00086703 00010601 00096133 00004187 00051466 00073467 00033290 00055016 00008613
00051479 00040071 00021629 00074462 00067683 00088355 00068604 00067850
398  %put &=var5;
VAR5=00085970 00089481 00066518 00064476 00066620 00012106 00053533 00088556 00096761 00052373 00076467 00049052
399  %put ALL=%superq(all);
ALL=&var1 &var2 &var3 &var4 &var5
400  %put &=all;
ALL=00072660 00092691 00069441 00076914 00000296 00086703 00010601 00096133 00004187 00051466 00073467 00033290 00055016 00008613
00051479 00040071 00021629 00074462 00067683 00088355 00068604 00067850 00020993 00076501 00081628 00054327 00055538 00088256
00034861 00069995 00062970 00032025 00092596 00090537 00045211 00099664 00096219 00048135 00069145 00024226 00060402 00060323
00090979 00078124 00054927 00064932 00031504 00007338 00022643 00000423 00086562 00067241 00020357 00063669 00028584 00051960
00065763 00012285 00098334 00078377 00065116 00055994 00077547 00045182 00057289 00046657 00070880 00030628 00052710 00089382
00042471 00014399 00019487 00067701 00013216 00065621 00023268 00052347 00079537 00072708 00082568 00056420 00010657 00027136
00064296 00004456 00070439 00031396 00085970 00089481 00066518 00064476 00066620 00012106 00053533 00088556 00096761 00052373
00076467 00049052
```

Comment: While `all = &var1 &var2` (quoted) gets around the length limit temporarily, there's no valid way to fully resolve that variable as far as I know. Worse, a lot of macro functions refuse to process *any* input above that length, so e.g. `%scan(&var1 &var2, ...)` will error if the combined length exceeds 65,534 even if each variable is under the limit. At best you can use the quoted `all` as a non-resolved list of lists to be processed separately, but `%put &all` (or any other full resolution) will definitely truncate/error if `&var1` + `&var2` is over the limit.

Comment: Useful for CODE generation, which is the main purpose of macro code. Not useful for macro functions, but why would you want to do that? If you want to work with that much data use SAS code instead of macro code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help guys.

I ended up using this code as an adicion to my prievieus one and it did exactly what i wanted.

```
%macro MAIN;
  %do j=1 %to &i.-1;
    %let used = &&ACC_&j.;
    %IF j NE 1 %then &used.;
        %else ,&used.;
  %end;
%mend;
%LOOP(CRDS_DATA, LOAN_IDENTIFIER);
```

But you were  corrent. If i want to filter more than million data the code becomes slower than datastep but bellow one mil. its great.